# Perspective is still visible even after uninstalling eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created a perspective named as "My Perspective" as a eclipse plugin.It shows properly but when i uninstall the plugin, this perspective still exist.How can i solve it programmaticly?

Comment: Where i have to use it in Java source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does this to support the somewhat common usecase:

1. working with eclipse with an add-on
   perspective
2. download version N+1 and start up
   (no add-on perspective)
3. install add-on plugins and restart
4. start up and add-on perspective
   comes back to life.

In an RCP app if you know you're uninstalling your add-on plugins you can close the perspective in the `org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.preShutdown()` method.  In the Eclipse IDE, you don't have access to that, although you might be able to use `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchListener.preShutdown(IWorkbench, boolean)`

Comment: Can you please explain me that how can i figure out that my plugin is uninstalled programmaticly.I am thinking to place this line in that.Please let me know this approach is right or should i go through other approach.I am uninstalling the plugin through Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way.  In an RCP app you control what the user can and can't do.  In Eclipse, it's the IDE.  Since the IDE policy is to leave the perspective there but disabled, the user can close it themselves.

Comment: Thanks for Reply.
But if i consider it and again install my plugin after uninstalling it shows me two Perspective.

1.icon<MyPerspective>
2.Myperspective

I am mugging up to solve this issue but not able to find out.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bug.  See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=217974 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294815